# Android espresso testing lock and unlock screen

Tags: android, automated-tests, lockscreen, android-espresso

I am trying to write an automated test to an android application that appears when you unlock your screen using the espresso framework. I would like to add a test case to ensure that an activity appears when the screen is unlocked.

How can I programmatically lock or unlock the screen using espresso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that [UiDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html) has the desired methods. My final code:

```
UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
    try {
        uiDevice.sleep();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        uiDevice.wakeUp();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```